# Using printf with parameters

Tags: php, parameters, printf

How can I use **printf** to work with parameters regardless of their type? (Something like binding parameters in a prepared statement in PDO).

E.g.:

```
printf("Hello $s, you have $s new notifications.", $username, $newNotifications);
```

I tried something like that and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [man page](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

Basically, you're using `$s` when you should be using `%s`. But you could just use `print` or `echo` with the string:

```
print "Hello ".$username.", you have ".$newNotifications." new notifications.";
```

Comment: You're right, I was using $s instead of %s. It works now, thanks.
Also, I find it much more clean to use parameters instead of concatenating if I'm dealing with a big string. That's why I wanted to use parameters

Comment: @JohnDoe quite contrary, in the long string you will have to count placeholders on your fingers

Answer (score 0):

`printf` needs to know how to format the arguments.  You could just `echo` them instead, using the `.` concatenation operator:

```
 echo "Hello " . $username . ", you have " . $newNotifications . " new notifications.";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Hello $username, you have $newNotifications new notifications.";
```

note that *good* syntax highlighter will  emphase variables in the string for the even better readability, making this way simply the best.